# How to change numpy mkl BLAS libraries?

Tags: python, numpy, blas, intel-mkl

So I just installed anaconda, and when I type `numpy.__config__.show()`, I get the following output:

```
blas_mkl_info:
libraries = ['mkl_rt']
library_dirs = ['C:/Anaconda3\\Library\\lib']
define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
include_dirs = ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\include', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IntelSWTools\\compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.246\\windows\\mkl\\lib', 'C:/Anaconda3\\Library\\include']
```

I have another python build (on separate computer) where the libraries = ['mkl_core_dll', 'mkl_intel_lp64_dll', 'mkl_intel_thread_dll']

My question is how do I change the anaconda build to include these different mkl libraries? I've tried messing with the site.cfg file in numpy, but no luck.

Also, does using different mkl libraries lead to different end results? I am really trying to get reproducible results between these two builds, and right now these different mkl settings seem to be messing it up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It supposedly does include the mkl libraries, since it's in `show_config()`. But I've seriously struggled recently with it on Windows

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, I know mkl is being used in numpy. But it appears to only be using 'mkl_rt', when my other build uses different mkl libraries. I would like the two builds to be identical. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: I still have matrix multiplication locked on a single core. I have spent days trying to get it working properly on Windows but it definitely uses multiple cores on Linux. I don't know what the issue is, tbh, but I'm kinda reassurered that I'm not alone. Something is not right.

Comment: It should be picking up any new MKL if yours are on the path. Expect for 2019.1 that seem to have some missing symbols.

Comment: And yes, it can lead to different numbers, even within the same platform (small diffs). You need to force MKL to use the same architecture. You might not need anything else, as I think only dot uses MKL.